# Azure AD config for SSO

Tags: azure, active-directory, app-config, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

Here is use case:

- I have a domain like http://example.com with port like 3020
- From this domain I request SAML request to azure AD to get token
- Azure after received request, will do a http POST contain a expected result to reply URL that was config in AD Azure.

The point is my reply config was http://example.com/consume then when http POST was executed, it choose default port 80. So Azure do a http POST to right IP but wrong port.

Any expert in config Azure AD ? Please help.

Comment: You can configure the port in the reply URL. Just specify it in AAD as `http://example.com:3020/consume`?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, too but this happened only request with domain http://example.com:3020 then replyURL will post to http://example.com:3020/consume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were developing an application to integrate Azure Active Directory single sign-on using the SAML, this is expected.

If we config the redirect URL in our web app, we also need to specify the **portal** in the reply URL, or it will use the default port of HTTP protocol(80). In this scenario, Azure AD will check whether the reply URL in the request([AssertionConsumerServiceUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-single-sign-on-protocol-reference#authnrequest)) match the `RedirectUri` of the cloud service in Azure AD.

Comment: yes, but if we do that then reply URL will contain portal right ? like `http://example.com:3020/consume`

Comment: Yes, it should use the reply URL include the port in the request.